# Can the space of Safe Area be filled with anything?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I would like to have a bottom aligned button which has text positioned above safe area in a way that allows me to fill that space with the color of button and, ideally, is clickable too.

I was thinking about adding a Container with Gesture Detector there but can't figure out how to do it in a way that won't ruin layout on phones without safe area. [That's how huge it looks when wrapped in SafeArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AtXK.png). Ideally there would be little to no margin above text in this button, something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO3qx.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) instead of SafeArea, knowing the bottom and top safearea height by these 2 functions:

ScreenUtil.bottomBarHeight  //Bottom safe zone distance, suitable for buttons with full screen
    ScreenUtil.statusBarHeight  //Status bar height , Notch will be higher Unit px

you can then control the height of safearea yourself